# Find dynamic data from MySQL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have a `MySQL` database and I take data from it using `Node JS`. I also use `AngularJS` for live searching in it. Here is part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="songlist" ng-controller='another_control'>
          <table id="songlistTableR" ng-app='test_table' ng-controller='main_control'>   
            <tr><th>Название</th><th>Ссылка</th></tr>    
            <tr ng-repeat="data in loaded | filter:search">
              <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{data.song_name}}</td>
              <td><a href="{{data.link}}" target='_blank'>Youtube</a></td>     
            </tr>
          </table>      
        </div>
```

Part of node server file:

```
app.get('/load',function(req,res){

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM test_table",function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) throw err;      
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));              
    });
});
```

And JS 'core' file:

```
app.controller('main_control',function($scope,$http){
    load();
    function load(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
            $scope.loaded=data;
        });
    }
});
```

**Question:** I need to have access to this data from database in another JS file. For example, I want to `alert(data[1].song_name)`. How to do it?

**UPD:** I've updated part of HTML code, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: i could not understand youre question so much, could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way will be using rootscope instead of scope,

```
app.controller('main_control',function($scope,$http, $rootScope){
    load();
    function load(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
            $rootScope.loaded=data;
        });
    }
});
```

you can access this data from any other directive, controller or service by injecting $rootScope then calling $rootScope.loaded

in another controller,

```
    app.controller('another_control',function($scope,$http, $rootScope){
        $scope.data = $rootScope.loaded;

        $scope.$watch('data', function(n) {
if(angular.isDefined(n)) {
alert(n[1].song_name);
}
})
    });
```

but since you are requesting async data, you either have to trigger this alert function by watching the value or with a button or something.

then later on, you can actually look into localstorage, services, etc. to come up with a better solution.

Comment: I understood about rootScope in this script, but how to inject rootScope in another JS file?

Comment: Thanks! Where to add `another_control` in HTML and why I can't use `main_control` also?

Comment: you don't want to use same controller allover your app., but you can also just extend your controller scope to cover more code. so define it in the body tag for example.  that's a pretty big scope though.

Comment: When it will work, i.e. I can alert($scope.data[1].song_name), I will accept of course

Comment: well your question has nothing to do with that though.

Comment: Should I also use this `var app = angular.module('test_table', []);`, or I need to choose another module? And where to put it in HTML, with `main_control` or with `another_control`?

Comment: My question is how to find this data. And to check that I found it, I alert it, but it didn't alert.

Comment: you should update your question at this point.  It's hard to understand what you really need.

Comment: hope it helps.  that's it from me :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think it will help if I put ng-app in a right place. Because if I put it in div `.songlist` the search doesn't work. And if I put in in table, alert will not work. Can you check my mistake?